# In using WCF, What data structure do I use to return a SQL Server query result that is formatted using FOR XML?

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, wcf

I'm using WCF to create a service that will query my SQL Server DB and return the response in a specific XML layout (shown here)

```
<SUP_LOCS>
    <SUP_LOC>
        <SUP_LOC_ID_DESC>Memphis TN</SUP_LOC_ID_DESC>
        <QTY_AVL>6</QTY_AVL>
        <ITEM_UOM>EA</ITEM_UOM>
    </SUP_LOC>
    <SUP_LOC>
        <SUP_LOC_ID_DESC>Los Angeles CA</SUP_LOC_ID_DESC>
        <QTY_AVL>1</QTY_AVL>
        <ITEM_UOM>EA</ITEM_UOM>
    </SUP_LOC>
</SUP_LOCS>
```

I am using FOR XML to make SQL Server produce the XML. This gives me the correct XML format I show above.

```
select location [Sup_LOC_ID_DESC] ...(shortened for brevity)... FOR XML raw('SUP_LOC'), root('SUP_LOCS'), elements
```

My question is what data structure should I use in my method? (shown here). In my example, I am using string but when I use the WCF test client, my response doesn't look like I thought it would (see image below)

```
public string GetInventory(string itemID)
{
    inventoryQuery = string.Format(inventoryQuery, itemID);
    string queryResult = _sub.Database.SqlQuery<string>(inventoryQuery).FirstOrDefault();
    return queryResult;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your return type can be `System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message` and you can create a message using `WebOperationContext.Current.CreateTextResponse` method

So, your method can be like

```
public System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message GetInventory(string itemID)
{
    inventoryQuery = string.Format(inventoryQuery, itemID);
    string queryResult = _sub.Database.SqlQuery<string>(inventoryQuery).FirstOrDefault();
    return WebOperationContext.Current.CreateTextResponse(queryResult,"text/xml");
}
```

Comment: Your code didn't work right out of the box for me. I had to do the following:   `[MessageContract]
    public class DataInput
    {
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public string itemID;
    }` and pass an object of this class into the method, but you definitely put me on the right path as it works now. Thanks.